# Split a RDD column into several ones in Scala

Tags: list, scala, rdd

I have a RDD of this form:

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int, Array[String])]
```

This is the first element of the RDD:

```
(001, 5, Array(a, b, c))
```

And I want to split that list on several columns, as it is separated by commas, the expected output would be:

```
(001, 5, a, b, c)
```

Any help?

SOLUTION:

I finally resolved the problem:
What I did was compose the array in a entire string with:
    mkstring(",")
and then, converted the rdd to dataframe. With that, I was able to  split the string in columns with the method withColumns

Comment: `yourRDD.map{case(i, n, List(a,b,c))=>(i,n,a,b,c))` probably but it's not entirely clear what you  mean as the elements are not "separated bv commas", that's just the way they are printed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to get values from the list one by one and put them into a tuple. Try this

```
val result = RDD.map(x => (x._1, x._2, x._3(0), x._3(1), x._3(2)))
```

Comment: Yes, that's a way, but what if I have a large number of elements in the list. Is there a way to iterate through them and returned them?

Comment: is the number of elements in the list fixed? @Thabby07

Comment: Yes, there are 298 items in the list.

Comment: @Thabby07 As far as I know, it is not possible to do that, because tuple in scala has a limited number 22 which means you can only have at most 22 columns in your RDD(T,T,T,T,T,T,T.....). Actually I dont suggest  to split elements in list into columns in RDD as reason mentioned by Sarvesh.

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like this,

```
RDD[(String, Int, List[String])]
```

In general you should not try to generate an RDD with elements of that List as columns.

The reason being the fact that Scala is a Strictly Typed language and your `RDD[T]` needs to be a `RDD` of type `T`.

Now lets say your RDD only had following two "rows" (elements) with lists of different lengths,

```
("001", 5, List("a", "b", "c"))
("002", 5, List("a", "b", "c", "d"))
```

Now as you can see... that the first row will need a `RDD[(String, Int, String, String, String)]` but the second will need a `RDD[(String, Int, String, String, String, String)]`.

This will result in the generated RDD to think of its type as `Any` and you will have an `RDD[Any]`. And this `Any` type will further restrict you in doing things because of `Erasure` at run-time.

But the special case where, you can do this without problem is - if you know that each list has `known and same` length (lets say 3 in this case),

```
val yourRdd = rdd.map({
  case (s, i, s1 :: s2 :: s3 :: _) => (s, i, s1, s2, s3)
})
```

Now... If it is not this special case and your lists can have different unknown sizes... and if even you want to do that... converting a list of unspecified length to tuple is not an easy thing to do. At least, I can not think of any easy way to do that.

And I will advise you to avoid trying to do that without a very very solid reason.